# (probably) simply AJAX / PHP question

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Here's the deal - I have two files, main.html and processing.php. Within the php file, I update certain element on main.html - but for whatever reason I'm having trouble getting either the html or javascript value from main.html

Example
main.html contains

```
   <span class="amount" id="money_amount">55</span>
```

processing.php contains a lot of stuff, of which this following line works (updates the money_amount id on the html page), where moneyWorks is a javascript variable

```
document.getElementById("money_amount").innerHTML = moneyAmount;
```

the following php code (in processing.php) does not work - i keep getting the value of 0 in $newbalance

```
  <?php
        $newbalance = $_GET['document.getElementById("money_amount").innerHTML'];  
        $sql = "UPDATE tbl_balance SET amount= " . $newbalance . " where userid = {$_SESSION['userid']}";
        //mysql_query($sql);
        echo "alert($newbalance)";
    ?>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Where is the Javascript/Ajax code? In the PHP code you have Javascript mixed in.

Comment: You can't execute JS in PHP, nor access the DOM. Learn some web development basics.

Comment: I hope this is just an example and in "real life" you sanitize your input.

Comment: `$newbalance = $_GET['document.getElementById("money_amount").innerHTML']; `? Really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something really dirty, but it works

```
   <span class="amount" id="money_amount">55</span>
  <img style="position:absolute;top:-20px;left:-20px;width:1px;height:1px;" src="about:blank" id="fake_request_image" />
```

and then you do somehting like

```
document.getElementById("fake_request_image").src='myPHPfile.php?moneyAmount='+document.getElementById("money_amount").innerHTML;
```

and then in the php file you got the right value in here:

```
$newbalance = $_GET['moneyAmount'];
```

;)

for this really dirty hack I probably deserve a downvote.. but it works.. so vote me up :P

Comment: sorry for not accepting, I was a little turned off from all the other comments

Answer (score 0):

From PHP you can only reach parameters passed on with a request, you cannot access an element that's on the client's browser. Normally this is done using a form and the $_POST variable in the php script.

Alternatively, you could, before calling process.php, call a javascript that reads the span's value, and adds it as parameter to the request (either GET or POST would work for this)